# Django admin change_view not called

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to redefine a ModelAdmin for a model in this way:

```
class MakeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    ...

    # def changeform_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    #     if not request.user.is_superuser:
    #         self.exclude = ('company',)
    #     extra_context = extra_context or {}
    #     return super().changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context,)

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.exclude = ('company',)
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        return super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context,)


admin.site.register(Make, MakeModelAdmin)
```

But method `change_view` is not called.

At the same time, the commented code `changeform_view` is called.
I checked and ModelAdmin contains both of methods.

I can't figure out why "change_view" is not called where "changeform_view" is called (obviously when uncommented).

Documentation suggests change_view:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view

I'm using Django 2.0.2

Answer (score 6):

`change_view` only get's called on the model instance editing page, so when editing an existing model instance

`changeform_view` will be called on all the pages for a model instance (add, edit and delete)

If you are adding a new model instance, you will need to use `add_view` instead.

`change_view`, `add_view` and `delete_view` are outlined in the docs
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view